# Eclipse: how to change into the correct perspective automatically when editing a file?

Tags: eclipse

I want to configure Eclipse to change into the appropriate perspective automatically when I open a file for editing.  For example if I am in Java perspective and open a MXML or ActionScript file then I want the perspective to change automatically to the FlashBuilder perspective .  Then if I reopen the Java file for editing it should switch back to the Java perspective .

I think I remember seeing a prompt asking if this should be the default behavior when I first installed Eclipse, and now I wish I had accepted that.  I can't find anything in the settings which allow me to configure this behavior. Is it possible, and if so how?

I am running Eclipse Helios Release 2 on a Windows machine.

Comment: When you create a new _project_ Eclipse asks if you want to switch to the respective perspective, e.g. PHP perspective for PHP projects. As far as I know you can't tie an Editor to a specific perspective. I actually think this is a useful behaviour. A perspective may offer a different perspective to a content object, e.g. if I open a Java file in JPA perspective I get a different perspective onto the content than when opening it in Java perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no native way that I know of (Eclipse 4.2.0). But you can use this plugin that works like a charm for my needs:

http://www.richinternet.de/blog/index.cfm?entry=1758AACF-910C-DE52-368E1421BEFDA19B

Comment: man, this is what I absolutely LOVE about eclipse - the plugin-able behavior (with LOTS of FREE plugins)! I needed 2 things: code zoom in/out capability + this automatic perspective change. 3 minutes for searching and copying 2 files and voila, problems solved! for me, it's better than any IDE out there (even VS). plus, it's becoming more and more stable nowadays - the Juno and Kepler releases simply rock! thank you for the helpful answer, btw

Comment: You're welcome. I love the looks of Eclipse as compared with NetBeans. However, Eclipse has some weird bug in it that makes copy-paste operations really slow and laggy. Moreover, it has a limited set of Java project templates as compared with NetBeans. No IDE can compare with the dark look and feel of Visual Studio 2013 though!

Comment: some words about the Eclipse vs. VS (pun intended) comparison from my perspective; eclipse is: highly customizable (can support a WIDE variety of programming languages and is already offering a lot of FREE super-useful plugins, unlike VS), portable (this includes the plugins, since they're written in Java), great editing features (I personally prefer it even over VS+VisualAssistX), becoming more and more stable (and a lot of bugs are actually in the plugins, not in the IDE itself), not requiring fancy dependencies (you can copy-paste it to another PC any time keeping the same configuration)ETC

Comment: I ran out of characters. I'd also mention some features I extensively  use when working with Eclipse: perspectives (different organization of windows for debugging/writing code/different languages), working sets: at the moment I'm writing an ARM mini-OS and I need to maintain it for a lot of different board; have working sets when I want to focus on developing for ONE of the boards is a blessing to me; how-many-you'd-like launch configurations, another feature missing from VS and that helps me a lot in eclipse...the list goes on, and this is only from personal practical views

Comment: one more thing to say and I'm done: the first high-level language I learned was C#, for which VS presumably offers the best support; at first I was very satisfied with how it behaved, given that I didn't really code advanced stuff; but in time I also wrote code for complex projects, with lots of related slns; learning that eclipse is far superior in comparison with VS was for me only a matter of using it for a 2-3 months; other facts: http://slashdot.org/topic/bi/visual-studio-vs-eclipse-a-programmers-matchup/ and http://jmonkeycoder.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/eclipse-vs-visual-studio/

Comment: Link is broken, could you post the name of the plugin?

Answer (score 9):

If you go into preferences -> general -> Editors -> File Associations, you can define the editor to associate with a given file.

I don't know if -- by mode -- you mean perspective, or view (editor).

**Edit**:  What other information were you looking for?  Does this not answer your questions?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Zack.  You're right, I meant perspective rather than mode; I will edit the original post to rectify my meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences -> General -> Perspectives and then you have the option to "Open the associated perspective when creating a new project" set it to "Always open".

Comment: Sounds like that's for opening a project, not for opening a file. But also a useful tip.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+Shift+F8---->you can change the perspective alternatively.This shortcut also may be helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

I just want to help @Piotr Dobrogost and @Tom Brito,
But I can not write the reply cause don't have enough reputation.
Then I write down on new comment:
1. You can access link http://www.richinternet.de/blog/
2. Then select Menu "Plugins", and roll down util to the title "New Perspective Switcher Plugin version"
[image]

Or you can access the link:  http://www.richinternet.de/blog/index0d2c.html?mode=cat&catid=79CCCF13-928B-FB2B-96BD8FE9AFA1FC47

File name: de.richinternet.plugins.perspectiveswitcher_0.1.1.jar
After download, I extract to dropins folder of eclipse (Version: 4.3.2)
This is capture of result:
[image]

Hope it usefull, thanks !